# Names of specific phobias

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

I need help. I'm trying to find the phobia names of these fears:

1. Fear of your own identity
2. Fear of not knowing

Comment: [This](http://phobialist.com/) list doesn't have one for either of those at a quick glance.  Not sure it's comprehensive but it sure looks like a lot of different phobia.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "fear of your own identity".  Do you mean fear of oneself? Do you mean fear of one's persona? Do you mean fearing that one does not have a distinct identity? Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there are unambiguous, widely used precise terms for this, but this is what I've come up with:

[autophobia](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/autophobia):

> a fear of being alone or of one's self

So this one has two meanings at best, and the fear of loneliness is the better known one. However there are sources that support the second meaning as well:

> *Autophobia may mean one of two things. First, it could mean that a person is scared of being alone or isolated. Second, if taken literally, it could mean an irrational fear of being oneself and is associated with self-hatred.* [Phobia Source](http://www.phobiasource.com/autophobia-fear-of-being-alone-or-of-oneself/).

The term seems to originate from the meaning you need:

> autophobia (n.) "fear of referring to oneself," 1845 (as autophoby), from Greek autos "self" (see auto-) + -phobia "fear." Related: Autophobic; autophobe. [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=autophobia&allowed_in_frame=0)

As for the other one, I'm not sure that there is a word.

**Agnosiophobia** can be found on the internet, but I couldn't find a proper definition. There is [a play](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSZtFAdPWnc) with this name, apparently about a man who has a fear of not knowing:

> *Night Terror Winner:
>   AGNOSIOPHOBIA
>   Written by Jason Gray Platt and based on a play by Giuseppe Giacosa
>   Directed by Rachel Karp
>   Featuring Matt Stango, Marlowe Holden, Jack Gilbert, and Ellie Phillips
>   A man’s curiosity threatens to destroy his family. Can he ignore the secrets of those he loves, **or will his fear of not knowing consume him?***
>
> (The Flea; bold emphasis mine)

The word might catch on, but for now the only argument for using it might be considering it the opposite of

[gnosiophobia](http://common-phobias.com/Gnosio/phobia.htm), the fear of knowledge.

Comment: I am highly sceptical that 'gnosiophobia' is a genuine phobia rather than an imaginary/concocted phobia invented by people who enjoy playing with words. If you Google the term, you'll find that it mostly occurs in lists of 'weird words', blogs of doubtful worth and websites that promote pseudoscientific 'cures'. Many of these sites also appear to have copied verbatim from each other their references to the word, which in itself calls into question the genuineness of the condition it purports to describe.

Comment: @ErikKowal I agree it isn't a clinical term; I think that some 'phobias' are used colloquially as well as in professional contexts, so this was what I meant (maybe I should have made that clearer). The terms I offered are even more in the gray area and I certainly wouldn't recommend them as technical terminology, but I think that this is the best there is so far for what the OP is asking. They didn't give the context in which they would use it so in some cases these might work; in other definitely not. .